# How to deal with semantic symbols for accessibility in HTML?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantics, symbols

I find this an interesting question, since there hasn't been any resource discussing this matter yet: how do you deal with symbols that has semantic meaning when writing accessible markup?

Examples would be symbols like "&", "$", "*", "-", "~", etc... Maybe the screen reader is smart enough to read "&" as "and", "$" as "dollar" and so on but some symbols don't always have definitive meaning in every scenario. For example, when you see "Jan 2 - 3, 2013" or "Jan 2 ~ 3, 2013" you know the "-" and "~" means "from ... to ...". But how do I encode that meaning into the markup? Should I use the `<abbr>` tag like `Jan 2 <abbr title="to">~</abbr> 3, 2013`?

Comment: You're used to reading hyphens as a range. Blind people are too.

Comment: `&` and `&amp;` will be read the same way. Some assistive tech will say "and" and others will say "ampersand." To be valid HTML you should use `&amp;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special with special characters. You're used to interpreting symbols for their various meanings, and people using assistive technology are also used to interpreting symbols for their various meanings as well.

The cases where you *would* need to add additional information would be when you use an image of a symbol, or a non-standard meaning.

Comment: I see, good point, but wouldn't it be weird if you hear "january two hyphen three, twenty thirteen"?

Comment: @Xavier_Ex, it's weird to you because you're not used to hearing it. For someone who regularly uses a screen reader it's quite natural. The purpose isn't for it to be reading like a human would, the purpose is to identify everything on the screen. Additionally, screen readers read through text much faster than you or I might feel comfortable with.

Comment: Ya I have seen people using assistive readers and they do speak pretty fast. All in all, you made good points about "things are accessible doesn't necessarily mean things are natural", or at least not necessarily natural to us who aren't relying on assistive agents.

Answer (score 5):

Screen readers have their own ways of reading characters, but they should not be expected to be particularly smart at that. For most special characters, they speak just some name for the character, independently of context and meaning.

There’s not much you can do about it. You could use `span` markup with `title` attribute containing an explanation, but it will mostly be ignored. There is somewhat better support for `abbr`, though it is questionable to use it for special characters. More importantly, as [a W3C WAI document](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H28.html) says, “JAWS 6.2 and higher and WindowEyes 5.0 and higher support the abbr and acronym elements. They can all be set to speak the title attribute when these elements are encountered, but this is not the default setting and is often not turned on by users.”

So what you can do is to write as naturally as possible, e.g. “January 2–3, 2013” (using an en dash rather than a hyphen, as per English style guides).

Comment: Thanks for you information, I'll make sure I always use natural and "correct" symbols for the cause.

Comment: Perhaps the `kbd` element is better than a `span`? Imagine marking up instructions for which special characters can be used in a password. By itself, `kbd` doesn't seem to convey the "content" to a screen reader, but with a title seems to do the trick: `<kbd title="exclamation point">!</kbd>`.